# Why R markdown always generates the same numbers when loading work space?

Tags: r

I've just noticed that R mark down always generates the same numbers when I begin with loading work space. For instance I type something like

```
load("C:/Users/Piotr/Documents/MyWorkSpace.RData")
rnorm(10,0,1)
```

and the result is always the same. In my instance this is

### [1]  1.2741648 -0.7905977 -0.4062481  0.3983397  0.3917316 -1.4122062

### [7]  0.6595976  0.5776770 -1.0952124  0.1878156

Can you explain it to me and tell my how can I deal with it? ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Random Number Generator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html) stores its current state in an hidden variable called `.Random.seed`.
When you load `MyWorkspace.RData`, you restore the state of RNG.

To reset the Random Number Generator, just delete `.Random.seed`

```
rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. What should I do to deal with it then?